# Scala class inheritance with same variable name

Tags: scala, inheritance

Why does scala complains for below code?

```
scala> class Http(var status: Int)
defined class Http

scala> case class Post(url: String, data: String, status: Int) extends Http(status)
<console>:8: error: overriding variable status in class Http of type Int;
 value status needs `override' modifier
       case class Post(url: String, data: String, status: Int) extends Http(status)
                                                  ^

scala> case class Post(url: String, data: String, sta: Int) extends Http(sta)
defined class Post
```

But this runs fine.

```
scala> class C(boo:Int)
defined class C

scala> case class D(far:Int, boo:Int) extends C(boo)
defined class D
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var status: Int` will create accessor methods, something like

```
def status() = this.status
def status(status: Int) {this.status = status}
```

case class creates these methods by default, so you have two methods with same signature, and scala requires you to add `override` keyword when overriding methods.

without `var` you only create class fields and they are not overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I think class Http must have a val for status

and so :

```
scala> class Http(val status: Int)
defined class Http

scala> case class Post(url: String, data: String, override val status: Int) extends Http(status)
defined class Post
```